# macOS fullscreen videos not using new space on Chrome/Edge

Tags: macos, mac, safari, google-chrome

Switched from Safari to Chrome/Edge. In Safari when I fullscreened a video it used a new space so I could keep using the other tabs I had opened on Safari. On Chrome/Edge whenever I fullscreen a video it uses the same space therefore I can't use the other tabs unless I exit fullscreen.

Is there anyway to force any other browsers to use the macOS API / idiom to play full screen videos in a new space?

Comment: I just tested this in Edge and it creates a new space when I open a video (YouTube) fullscreen.  I can't replicate the issue.  Can you provide more details.?

Comment: I really don't know what else to tell, by new space you mean like the video tab says "click to exit full screen" whereas the other tabs can be used? I found a old (2014) thread with similar issue where one of the comments said to go to chrome://flags and search for "simplified full screen" but I can't find this option.

Comment: Before opening Edge/Chrome in full screen, open [Mission Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) by pressing the F3 key and see check the spaces.  Then, launch your video in full screen and press F3 again - it should be running in it's own space.

Comment: Before I open a video in fullscreen, Chrome is on desktop (not fullscreen) but when I open the video Chrome goes into the new space and comes back to dekstop when I exit fullscreen. On Safari when I open a video in fullscreen the video goes to new space but Safari itself is still on dekstop thats why I can still use the other tabs I have opened. This way I can pause a video, do some task on Safari and then swipe to my video. On Chrome, I have to exit fullscreen to do any task on chrome and then fullscreen again.

Comment: This seems to be Safari opens a new Safari window automatically for full screen videos whereas Chrome/Edge does not.  Why not just open your video in a new window manually for the same effect?

Comment: How do you that? Isn't there a way to make Chrome do that automatically?